# Помогите расставить знаки препинания:

Tags: пунктуация

Вся в сером(?) предвесеннем свете(?) моя комната

(Я понимаю, что слова можно поменять местами, но желателен этот вариант).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) **Вся в сером предвесеннем свете моя комната.**

(2) **Вся в сером, предвесеннем свете моя комната.**

Пояснение

1) Отношения между прилагательными можно считать однородными или неоднородными.

**Однородные** (сближенные) отношения между прилагательными (раскрытие общей темы — определения цвета), запятая ставится.

**Неоднородные** прилагательные называют разные признаки, нет сближения,  нет запятой.

2) **Инверсия** подлежащего (комната) и составного именного сказуемого делается для логического выделения сказуемого.